# Beginner C++ question about program design with unique_ptr and vectors

Tags: c++

I am currently making a console program about buying property in a city. Properties can be bought from the city by someone, transferred to another person, or returned to the city if the person who has ownership dies.

I have created 3 classes: Person, City, and Property. My Person and City classes both have vectors of unique_ptrs of Property. My main.cpp has a City unique_ptr and a vector of Person unique_ptrs and does basic initialization.

```
class Person {
    string name;
    vector<unique_ptr<Property>> ownedProperties;
    public:
        string getName();
        vector<unique_ptr<Property>> const& getOwnedProperties();
};

class City {
    string name;
    vector<unique_ptr<Property>> ownedProperties;
    public:
        string getName();
        vector<unique_ptr<Property>> const& getOwnedProperties();
};

class Property {
    string name;
    int id;
    public:
        int getID();
        string getName();
}

int main() {
    int numProperties;
    vector<unique_ptr<Person>> people;
    unique_ptr<City> city;
    //  initializing everything
    printAllProperties();
}
```

I decided to use unique_ptr because I am thinking of making subclasses of Property later and because I want to make sure that a Property only has one owner. I am using move() to transfer ownership between the Property vectors of City and Person. I am also printing out information like this:

```
City: San Johncisco
ID | Property Name | Owner
0  | A             | John
1  | B             | San Johncisco
2  | C             | Johnny
3  | D             | Johnathan
4  | E             | San Johncisco
5  | F             | Johnalina
6  | G             | Johnatha
```

The problem is that because I want to print the properties in order, I end up having something like this:

```
for (int currentID = 0; currentID < numProperties; currentID++) {
    for (auto property: city->getOwnedProperties()) {
        if (property->getID() == currentID) {
            // print info
        }
    }
    for (auto person: people) {
        for (auto property: person->getOwnedProperties()) {
            if (property->getID() == currentID) {
                // print info
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This looks really ugly and I feel as though I could've designed the program / method better. Any advice?

Comment: Your use of vectors of unique pointers does not satisfy your goals of having a property be uniquely sited in one city and uniquely owned by one person. It doesn't even prevent a city or a person from having multiple entries for the same property. And since they are vectors of unique pointers, a pointer to a property owned by an person points to a different object than does the corresponding pointer in the City's vector of property pointers. You might want to rethink your architecture as a whole rather than the narrow question you raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into `std::map`. It's a mapping between one value and another. In your case, it looks like you want to have a map of `ID`s to `Property`s. You can create one like so:

```
std::map<int,Property> propertyIDMap;
```

You can add properties to it by `id` like so:

```
propertyIDMap [ id ] = property;
```

And you can get properties out of it by ID by doing the following:

```
Property myProperty = propertyIDMap [ id ];
```

You may also want a mapping between property IDs and people. Although, if the `Property` kept a link back to its owner, you wouldn't need to do any lookup. Your loop would become:

```
for (int currentID = 0; currentID < numProperties; currentID++) {
    Property nextProperty = propertyIDMap [ currentID ];
    Person owner = nextProperty.owner;
    // print info
}
```